# Navigation Jquery Mobile + PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm having problem understanding how to work with the Jquery Mobile Navigation system.
I understanding that Jquery Mobile works with ajax according to this [link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/widgets/navigation/).
my Questions are:
1. I builded 2 Html files as client side in Phonegap that gets its dynamic content via Json, one is a login.html with login form that I use to validate via jquery validation plugin, and upon success it redirect to the page mainpage.html via the method $mobile.changepage() as shown here:

```
$("#LoginForm").validate({
    rules: {
        UserName:
            {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                rangelength: [4, 4]
            },
        Password: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            rangelength: [4, 4]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        UserName: {
            required: "שגיאה!, אנא הכנס שם משתמש",
            digits: "שגיאה!, אנא הכנס ספרות בלבד",
            rangelength: "שגיאה!, השדה חייב להיות 4 תווים בדיוק"
        },
        Password: {
            required: "שגיאה!, אנא הכנס סיסמה",
            digits: "שגיאה!, אנא הכנס ספרות בלבד",
            rangelength: "שגיאה!, השדה חייב להיות 4 תווים בדיוק"
        }
    },
    errorClass: 'input-validation-error',
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        /* Send the data using post */
        $.post("/Account/postLogin", $("#LoginForm").serialize(), function (data) {
            switch (data) {
                case "RESULT_SUCCESS":
                    $.mobile.changePage("/Home/NewTickets", { transition: "slide" });
                    break;
                case "UserNotFound":
                    alert("שם משתמש לא נמצא");  //phonegap error dialog
                    break;
                case "NonCorrectPassword":
                    alert("סיסמה אינה נכונה");  //phonegap error dialog
                    break;
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert("שגיאת שרת אינה יודעה, נסה שנית במועד מאוחר יותר");   //phonegap error dialog
        })
    }
});
```

in my mainpage.html I have a logout button that when I pressed it will do this method:

```
$('#logout').on('click', function () {
    $.get("/Account/Logout")
    .done(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("/Account/Login", { transition: "slide", reverse: true });
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("שגיאה!, לא היה ניתן להתנתק מן המערכת");
    });
});
```

upon testing it on iphone it does returning to the login.html, but when I press the "submit" button again it gives me an error message, I guess that is something to do with the 2 page already in the DOM, how do I fix it?

2.what is the main diffrence between the methods $mobile.changepage() vs $mobile.Navigate()
besides the fact that $mobile.Navigate() is newer according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616538/jquery-mobile-navigate-or-changepage), and what method should I use, and an example of the diffrences between them will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: I can't figure out where to begin.  Can you break this down into concise self-contained questions?

Comment: my question is how to move between 2 html pages using $mobile.changepage() on a dynamic pages.

Comment: and I'm gettin a yellow type error message of jquery mobile, that said: "ISMSGOR LOADING PAGE"

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit jumbled but I'll take a stab

1. JQM uses a single base page and then loads everything else via AJAX. You got that much. Does your second page contain a `data-role="page"` block?
2. I've not had good luck with JQM 1.3 or later yet. I would stick with `$.mobile.changepage()` until they get it worked out. It won't be removed soon, if ever.

Comment: I think that should be `$.mobile.changepage()`

Comment: Yes, my second page contain `data-role="page"`.