# go to next page with PhoneGap & JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I dont know what I have missed, but the thing is that I would like to have an action on my "add"-button so it can go to the next page "page2".

The same will be with the "show" and "cancel" button to get to previous and next page.
In my PhoneGap app I have a index.html and a index.js file, there is no page2.html and so on.

Can someone help me & explain how its done.

Thank you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Last Time I Did It!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a data-role="button" onclick="addEvent" id="add" data-rel="page">ADD</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-role="button" id="show" data-rel="page">SHOW</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="content">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a data-role="button" id="save">SAVE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-role="button" id="cancel" data-rel="page">CANCEL</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page3">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ol data-role="listview" id="orderedList" data-inset="true"></ol>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a data-role="button" id="edit">EDIT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-role="button" id="delete">DELETE</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my index.js file:

```
function addEvent()
{
 window.location = "page2.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code in your body tag.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">            
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a data-role="button" href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="add" data-rel="page">ADD</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-role="button" href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="show" data-rel="page">SHOW</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">            
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a data-role="button"  href="#page3" data-transition="slide" id="save">SAVE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-role="button" href="#page1" id="cancel" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="page">CANCEL</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#page2"  class="ui-btn-left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ol data-role="listview" id="orderedList" data-inset="true"></ol>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a data-role="button" id="edit">EDIT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-role="button" id="delete">DELETE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ved, it works now with this code added to my body. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this JSFiddle can help you [JSFiDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/g5vAN/)

For better understanding you can read here too [jQuery Mobile navigate or changePage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616538/jquery-mobile-navigate-or-changepage)

```
   <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
            <h1>Index page</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" id="navigateButton">Navigate to the other page</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
            <h1>Second page</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>
    </div>   

   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
      $(document).on('click', '#navigateButton', function(){        
        $.mobile.navigate( "#second", { transition : "slide", info: "info about the #bar hash" });
      });   
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding a **event listener** to the element which calls the **changepage** event.
This helped me boost up user experience, since it fires quicker than the **href** anchor.

```
$(document).on('tap', '#add', function(e){
    $.mobile.changePage('#page2');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
window.location.href = "page2.html"
```

but how do you expect to go to page2 if there is no page2.html?

Comment: I made 3 pages with JQuery Mobile "https://01.org/rib/online/" and I only got one index.html with that code inside. 
Should I make page2.html & page3.html and put the divs inside each html file?